# urlreq.pathname2url not returning enough slashes?

Tags: url, python-3.x, urllib

Windows 7, Python 3.3. I'm using the following method to generate URLs to files and folders on our shared drive:

```
import urllib.request as urlreq
   ...
urlreq.urljoin('file:', urlreq.pathname2url(path))
```

If path starts with a drive letter, then the above adds three slashes to the front and returns:

```
file:///Z:/foo
```

Which is exactly what I need. But if path starts with our network path "//WDSHARESPACE" (Correction: "\WDSHARESPACE") then I'm getting

```
file://WDSHARESPACE/Public/foo
```

Which works with IE, but not with Firefox. (Firefox wants the three slashes, plus the original two), so:

```
file://///WDSHARESPACE/Public/foo
```

Is there an elegant way to accomplish this, or do I need to test for the different cases? I'm not real strong in HTML coding, so would prefer not to.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.pathname2url):

> Convert the pathname path from the local syntax for a path to the form used in the path component of a URL

The 'local syntax' on windows uses backslashes, not forward slashes. So if you pass `//WDSHARESPACE`, the forward slashes are not treated specially in any way.

Just have a look at the [implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a222a015e28d/Lib/nturl2path.py#l35) to see what's really going on. If the path doesn't start with a drive letters or two backslashes, the function just converts backslashes to forward slathes and quotes the rest.

Also note this part of the docstring:

> not recommended for general use

Comment: Sorry mata. I had been using the proper backslashes and got the result I had posted. I accidentally typed forward slashes when posted my question.